# What is the best (fastest) way to connect my iMac Late 2012 to a Synology NAS?

Tags: network, time-machine, imac, thunderbolt, nas

I have an iMac Late 2012 with Thunderbolt 2 and USB3.0 ports and a Synology NAS DS916+ with USB 3.0 and eSATA ports.

Currently both devices connected to a router by wire (1Gbps). I do backups of my Mac (Time Machine) to the NAS and store my files there too.

I're recently experienced a long (around 20 hrs) recovery of iMac from Time Machine so I am wondering is there any faster way to connect my Mac to NAS? Is it worth to get some wires to connect them, or it's just money wasted?

Is it better to connect them with a USB 3 cable or some combination of wires Thunderbolt 2 to eSata?